# Hibernate grammar exception using JPA with hsqldb

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, hsqldb, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to write a persistence test. I have a Maven project and am using Arquillian with an embedded glassfish container, Hibernate (as my JPA provider) and HSQLDB in memory as my store.

When I run my test I get a grammar exception (I can post the full stack trace if necessary:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Syntax error: Encountered "identity" at line 1, column 6.
```

The logs seem to show the table created properly:

```
Hibernate: 
    create table Game (
        id bigint generated by default as identity (start with 1),
        title varchar(50) not null,
        primary key (id)
    )
Dumping old records...
Hibernate: 
    delete 
    from
        Game
Inserting records...
Hibernate: 
    insert 
    into
        Game
        (id, title) 
    values
        (default, ?)
Hibernate: 
    drop table Game if exists
Hibernate: 
    drop table Member if exists
```

I've included what I think are the relevant files

- persistence.xml
- pom.xml
- Entity class
- Test class

**persistence.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <class>Member</class>
    <class>Game</class>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>

         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"     />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url"     value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:demodb" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="sa" />
         <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />


         <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"     />
         <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop" />
         <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
         <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />

    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>....</groupId>
    <artifactId>....</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>Web App</name>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <netbeans.hint.deploy.server>gfv3ee6</netbeans.hint.deploy.server>
        <arquillian.version>1.0.0.Alpha2</arquillian.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.9</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.9.Final</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
                <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>arquillian-glassfish-embedded</id>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
                    <artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-embedded-3.1</artifactId>
                    <version>1.0.0.CR3</version>
                    <scope>test</scope>
                </dependency>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.glassfish.main.extras</groupId>
                    <artifactId>glassfish-embedded-all</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1.2</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.13</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>6.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <finalName>....</finalName>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
            <id>hibernate-support</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library Library[hibernate-support]</name>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <url>http://ftp.ing.umu.se/mirror/eclipse/rt/eclipselink/maven.repo</url>
            <id>eclipselink</id>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <name>Repository for library Library[eclipselink]</name>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
</project>
```

**Entity**

```
//imports removed

@Entity
public class Game implements Serializable {
    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;
    private String title;

    public Game() {}

    public Game(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @NotNull
    @Size(min = 3, max = 50)
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Game@" + hashCode() + "[id = " + id + "; title = " + title + "]";
    }
}
```

**Test class*

```
//imports removed

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GamePersistenceTest {

    @Deployment
    public static Archive<?> createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class, "test.war")
                .addPackage(Game.class.getPackage())
                .addAsResource("META-INF/persistence.xml")
                .addAsWebInfResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }
    private static final String[] GAME_TITLES = {
        "Super Mario Brothers",
        "Mario Kart",
        "F-Zero"
    };
    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    UserTransaction utx;

    // tests go here
    @Test
    public void shouldFindAllGamesUsingJpqlQuery() throws Exception {
        // given
        String fetchingAllGamesInJpql = "select g from Game g order by g.id";

        // when
        System.out.println("Selecting (using JPQL)...");
        List<Game> games = em.createQuery(fetchingAllGamesInJpql, Game.class).getResultList();

        // then
        System.out.println("Found " + games.size() + " games (using JPQL):");
        assertContainsAllGames(games);
    }

    private static void assertContainsAllGames(Collection<Game> retrievedGames) {
        Assert.assertEquals(GAME_TITLES.length, retrievedGames.size());
        final Set<String> retrievedGameTitles = new HashSet<String>();
        for (Game game : retrievedGames) {
            System.out.println("* " + game);
            retrievedGameTitles.add(game.getTitle());
        }
        Assert.assertTrue(retrievedGameTitles.containsAll(Arrays.asList(GAME_TITLES)));
    }

    @Before
    public void preparePersistenceTest() throws Exception {
        clearData();
        insertData();
        startTransaction();
    }

    private void clearData() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
        System.out.println("Dumping old records...");
        em.createQuery("delete from Game").executeUpdate();
        utx.commit();
    }

    private void insertData() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
        System.out.println("Inserting records...");
        for (String title : GAME_TITLES) {
            Game game = new Game(title);
            em.persist(game);
        }
        utx.commit();
        // clear the persistence context (first-level cache)
        em.clear();
    }

    private void startTransaction() throws Exception {
        utx.begin();
        em.joinTransaction();
    }

    @After
    public void commitTransaction() throws Exception {
        utx.commit();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It was a problem with my persistence.xml. I believe that I was missing an attribute on the db URL to create the DB `create=true`. I also along the way dropped the JPA config in favour of the Hibernate properties. Although, I haven't tested it, I expect only the first change was needed. My working file is below in case anyone ever needs it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="JTA">
        <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
        <class>Member</class>
        <class>Game</class>
        <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:demodb;create=true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.DerbyDialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create-drop"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>         
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>

</persistence>
```

Comment: `create=true` shouldn't be necessary as the property is true by default. `create=false` is used when you want to ensure the database is already created when the new connection attempt is made

Comment: @fredt Thanks for the update. I had been making a number of changes at the time, and havent had a chance to re-visit this. I'll re-test later and post an EDIT if needed